# ClearInterval doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create some loaders. One loader works fine, but when I create a few, clearInterval - doesn't stop the counter.

```
<p id='sk1'></p>

(function (){
  i = 0;
  function name(){
   var x = $('#sk1').text(i+=1);
   if( i==50 ){ clearInterval(z);}
  }
  var z = setInterval(name,10);
})();
```

[FIDDLY](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/19/)

Comment: i dont see a `clearinterval` in the fiddle

Comment: @SunilHari: There are 4 of'm in there -.-

Comment: previous fiddle was about some circle rotating

Comment: seems to work fine here -> http://jsfiddle.net/5er3jpun/ (chrome)

Comment: sorry - confused the links, UPDATED!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are defining `i` in the global scope. Use the `var` keyword to keep `i` within the scope of each anonymous function.

Currently, the same `i` variable, is being incremented 4 times every 10ms. The fact that your second timer stops is just coincidence that `i` lands on 66 at some point and clearing your interval relies on `i` equalling *n*, not `i` being more than or equal to *n*.

```
(function (){
  //Here
  var i = 0;
  function name(){
   var x = $('#sk1').text(i+=1);
   if( i==50 ){ clearInterval(z);}
  }
  var z = setInterval(name,10);
})();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/20/)

Comment: @fresa Glad to have helped :)